# Enum set in spring Roo

Tags: enums, spring-data-jpa, spring-roo

I've an Enum, and a class that could refer to multiple constants in that enum.

```
enum type --class ~.model.Vertical
enum constant --name PUBLICSECTOR --class ~.model.Vertical
enum constant --name HEALTHCARE   --class ~.model.Vertical
```

what I need is something like this, a Vendor can be present in both Verticals, so I need a collection of the selected enum constants:

```
focus --class ~.model.Vendor
field set --fieldName inVerticals --type ~.model.Vertical
```

Is there a way to create an EnumSet in Spring Roo? the field set seems to be for table relationships.

Comment: Why exactly isn't this just plain Java code? The spring roo DSL looks more verbose and less flexible, at least for this purpose...

Comment: It's to get all the definitions scripted into a one roo script.